# Bootstrap columns not in container and no space between them

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

Why my columns are overriding container-fluid padding? And also why there is no space between these columns? ..
I added an image with the issue.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="content">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-8 my-3 text-left bg-primary">
        <p>Hifgrdsgde </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 my-3 text-left bg-info">
        <p>Hifgrdsgde </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: "Rows are wrappers for columns. Each column has horizontal padding (called a gutter) for controlling the space between them. This padding is then counteracted on the rows with negative margins. This way, all the content in your columns is visually aligned down the left side."

Comment: You can resolve this by giving `margin:0px` to `row` class in your custom css file.

Comment: Thanks. Also, how can I add space between the columns? Only bootstrap cards do that I think. Is it possible for columns?

Comment: You have to manually add the margins to columns. Alternatively, you can wrap elements inside a column in a div and then apply padding to it.

Comment: I tried adding margin, whenever I add even 1px margin it changes from row to column

Comment: Should i use bootstrap cards instead?

Comment: @zyzzbruh There are margins between the columns called "gutters" which you just can't see because you have given your columns background colors. If instead you applied the background color a child element container in the column(s) you would see your gutter spacing, something like `<p class="bg-primary h-100">Hifgrdsgde </p>` and remove the bg color from the columns. Also `text-left` is default, probably don't even need the class.

Answer (score 0):

When you use classes on the column tag, it affect on that. So you should make a new div tag in the column and use bg-color class on that. Please change your source to this:

```html
<div id="content">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8 my-3 text-left">
                <div class="bg-primary">
                    <p>Hifgrdsgde </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 my-3 text-left">
                <div class="bg-info">
                    <p>Hifgrdsgde </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```